# Can anyone help identify this passenger steamship with double funnels and two masts?

Tags: identification, ships, historical-research, photography, nautical

[image]I believe that this unidentified passenger steamship could possibly be from the New England area or the Great Lakes. I have already ruled out this vessel as being the S.S. Boston of the Eastern steamship lines, as well as the S.S. North American. The time frame of the photograph is from 1907-1914. Thank you for any leads in identifying this vessel.

Comment: I tried to find a match to the funnel and house flag in https://research.mysticseaport.org/item/l011061/l011061-c008, without much luck.  Number 47 seemed closest, but not really plausible.

Comment: Anything more that can be said about this photo? Personally, I'm intrigued how its clearly black and white, but there's blue in it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks very similar to [S. S. Harvard](https://www.history.navy.mil/our-collections/photography/numerical-list-of-images/nhhc-series/nh-series/NH-105000/NH-105914-KN.html) pictured here in 1907:

[image]

Comment: I agree! How did you find it?

Comment: @kimchilover: A simple Right-Click -> Search Image With Google Lens. It was the third result.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, The S.S Harvard had a sister ship the S.S Yale which was was built by the Delaware River Iron Shipbuilding and Engine Works in 1906, for service between New York and Boston. This would make sense because the group of photos this came from are of vessels from the Boston and Cape Cod area. Thank you very much for your detective work. I very much appreciate it. I’m not sure how you figured it out though. I had been searching for a few weeks now.

Comment: @DaveMose: Seriously: my research took less than 2 minutes. **Right-Click -> Search Image With Google Lens**; then check a few of the top results and right up this answer.

Comment: @DaveMose - Our users are *really good* at this.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: Google Lens is not available on all combinations of OS and browser.  I see no such thing with Firefox under AlmaLinux for example.

Comment: The similarity is indeed quite striking. However, the original has a 'black square' opening in the middle below the two funnels. While that may be simply 'closed' in Q, I see not a hint of this on Harvard. And towards the stern there seem to be, IDK, two more funnels (?). These may be part of the skyline, or the ship? Can you clarify these, and add a bit more _textual description_ on how this 'match' does fit the original?

Comment: @DaveMose Info such as, how you narrowed your own search so far, or especially _ "the group of photos this came from"_ should really be in the question text!

Comment: Apparently this was a standard design, because several other [Eastern Steamship Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Steamship_Lines) ships such as the _[Bunker Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Aroostook_(CM-3))_ (later _Aroostook_) and _[Governor Cobb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Governor_Cobb)_ look like this.

Comment: @LangLangC Given the angle of those other funnels, they are likely from a different ship, behind this one.

Comment: Anyway, OP's ship is more likely to be _Yale_ than _Harvard_, because of the extent of the name lettering on the bow  relative to the portholes beneath.

Comment: @DaveMose I wonder if the S.S. Harvard and S.S. Yale ever had races....